# AWS: VPC and NodeJS

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, node.js, amazon-vpc

I'm transitioning from a dedicated server to a VPC in AWS. It's a NodeJS application baed on ExpressJS. In the current implementation, I have NGINX + Passenger in front of the NodeJS application for static assets.

In AWS, I'm creating a VPC. I will have a load balancer as the entry point, then EC2 instances, with the NodeJS application. What I'm not sure is if I will need an instance with NGINX as well in front of NodeJS instances. Would be a real benefit? I would also have to create multiple instances of NGINX to make it highly available.

Comment: No, you can have the instance running both nginx and node. Aside from that I suspect your question is a duplicate of [this one](http://serverfault.com/q/413108/126632).

Comment: can that be setup with OpsWorks without a custom Chef recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Michael's advice and created a custom recipe that sets up Nginx on all instances where I run NodeJS.