# Is there an advantage to using NGINX for reverse proxy over Tomcat's built-in proxying?

Tags: nginx, tomcat, amazon-elb

We have an application that runs in Tomcat on an EC2 instance.  We have an ELB in front of the EC2 that is configured with the following listeners:

```
ELB          
port 80   --> nginx  port 80   --> redirect |
port 443 <--> tomcat port 8080           <---
```

On the EC2 instance we have nginx running and performing reverse proxy to redirect connections on port 80 to port 8080 (Tomcat).  Here is the config:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Tomcat, running on the same server, is configured for port 8080:

```
   <Connector port="8080" 
    maxThreads="300" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

Most of the time, this works fine, but this creates problems in a small number of cases when our application returns non-HTTPS traffic. In researching the problem I found [this article](https://willwarren.com/2014/01/27/running-apache-tomcat-with-ssl-behind-amazon-elb/).

The system as is was configured partially by a contractor, who favored using nginx running on the EC2 instance as the reverse proxy.  My question is, is there an advantage in our use case of using nginx as the reverse proxy when it is running on the same server, if Tomcat can perform the same function and also redirect the non-secure traffic over the secure port (as seen in the linked article)?  Why use nginx at all in this case?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/413442/126632

Comment: @MichaelHampton My use case is a little different -- Tomcat is already handling requests to port 8080, only 80 is being redirected (to ensure that everything comes in over HTTPS).  We aren't concerned about static files or caching, as our app has few static resources and relatively little traffic.  Performance isn't a concern for the time being.  I have updated the "diagram" to reflect the current configuration.