# Is Tomcat Enough?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I built a JSP/glassfish/derby db web app locally using netbeans. So now I want to deploy it to the web. I have signed up for an unmanaged VPS through A2.

I realize I may be in over my head a little bit here but I have basic linux experience and I have set up tomcat before locally. When I go to my domain I get a 502 bad gateway error. The technical support at A2 is not very technical, and little help.

I'm pretty sure I have tomcat7 setup correctly and my webapp deployed. It listens to port 8080. My question is: is tomcat enough ? Or do I really need to install something else in order to have my remote site function properly ?

I am only vaguely aware of the difference between Tomcat and Apache. The remote host is Ubuntu and is completely bare bone so I am working on setting everything up. Any advice or additional steps I should follow ? Anything will help.

Comment: Related: [Is it bad practice to run a web application server directly on port 80/443](https://serverfault.com/q/413108/126632)

Comment: Thanks! So basically I need to install and configure apache then proxy to tomcat ? Please bare with me. I have read my self in circles. Any good resources on how to setup the basic structure will help.

Comment: Sorry, one thing we don't do here is [provide tutorials, books, etc.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Basically, you don't *need* to do anything besides changing tomcat from port 8080 to 80. If you need a proxy, I'd recommend haproxy.